# Accessing a table without specifying the schema name

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a schema called `GBO_ARC_SCHEMA`, in which I have one table called `TEST_EMP`,
and I have two users say `USER_A` and `USER_B`.

First I connected to `USER_A` and fired below query

```
select count(*)from TEST_EMP;

count
-----
20
```

After that I connected as `USER_b` and fired below query but it is giving an error, saying that table or view does not exit

```
select count(*)from TEST_EMP;
```

But if I use `scma.object name` it is allowing me to query like below

```
select count(*)from GBO_ARC_SCHEMA.TEST_EMP;
```

but as per my requirement I don't want to specify schema name.

can somebody help me out?

Comment: `i don't want to specify schema name`. Then simply [create a synonym](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7001.htm#SQLRF01401).

Comment: thanx but we dnt want to create the synonym my req is like that im passing table_name as dynamic if i use synonym it wont be generic ri8 ..??

Comment: If your query's dynamic (generated), why don't you simply add the schema in there while you're building the query?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want *all* users to be able to select from the table without qualifying with the schema name, you want to create a *public synonym*:

```
create public synonym TEST_EMP for GBO_ARC_SCHEMA.TEST_EMP;
```

If you only want `user_b` to omit the schema name, you want to create a *private synonym* WITHIN user_b's schema (that is logged on as user_b)

```
create synonym TEST_EMP for GBO_ARC_SCHEMA.TEST_EMP;
```

**If you insist** on not using synonyms, then, after logging in, do a

```
alter session set current_schema = GBO_ARC_SCHEMA;
```

Comment: Excuse me, but where do you see sequences?

Comment: thanq so much friends i have considered alter session set current_schema = GBO_ARC_SCHEMA;

Comment: alter session set current_schema = GBO_ARC_SCHEMA; is working fine now

Answer (score 1):

On the server roles for the login you are using, simply uncheck sysadmin and serveradmin roles.
That should solve it

Answer (score -2):

For Postgres users with the same problem

```
ALTER ROLE <YOUR_USERNAME> SET search_path TO GBO_ARC_SCHEMA;
```

Comment: This is Oracle, not Postgres.