# mysql postgresql query without specifying table name and public folder

Tags: mysql, postgresql

My client requests to change from using MySQL to PostgreSQL. The database migration ran well, and my codes are using DevArt dotConnect Universal. Things are looking good except for the actual SQL statement.

In my C# code I used,

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name LIKE '%abc%';"
```

and it worked with MySQL, but when it is connected to the PostgreSQL, I have to change the SQL statement to use,

```
"SELECT * FROM public.\"users\" WHERE user_name LIKE '%abc%';"
```

and the searched text is case-sensitive!

How do I, 
(a) make the searched text case insensitive? 
(b) avoid needing to add [public.] in front of the table name and to double-quote the table name?

I have seen someone posted something here, [Accessing a table without specifying the schema name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846648/accessing-a-table-without-specifying-the-schema-name)
but I have 120 tables and it will be time consuming. Is there any faster approach to solve my 2 issues described above?

**EDIT:**
Oh I realized these two statements yields the same result.

```
SELECT * FROM Public.user;
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM \"user\";
```

Comment: AFAIK you shouldn't need to specify the public schema. You only need to double-quote the table name if it's not all in lower case and has no spaces or other "funny" characters - although I don't know if that's true for dotConnect... Non-case sensitive is easy - use ILIKE.

Comment: There is no need to qualify the table name with the `public` schema (unless you messed around with the default search path). You also don't need to quote the table name if you created the tables without quoting. And yes character comparison *is* case sensitive in Postgres

Comment: Thank you both of you. I noticed something in the database as it was done by their previous programmer. Incidentally she used keywords as column names such as "type". Of course I can change it to "fruit_type" but not only I have to change in all 120 tables, I have to alter the codes and the Crystal Report too. Any faster approach?

Comment: If `SELECT * FROM Public.user;` works, then `select * from users` (without any quotes) will work just as well. And you *can* use `type` as a table name without the need to quote it in Postgres: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/740cb/1

Comment: Thank you guys, I will look into it. Hopefully I get can something by Friday.

Answer (score 1):

*(a) make the searched text case insensitive?*

> ILIKE keyword in PostgreSQL provides case insensitive  search

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name ILIKE '%abc%';`

or

`select * from words where LOWER(word) LIKE '%aba%'`

Note: if your table name is  `Users` then use `SELECT * FROM "Users"`

[> SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/12586/2)

Comment: Thank you @WingedPanther for your speedy response. The SQLFiddle Demo is good, I will use it. I have also listed another question as to how to select without using Public keyword and How can I not double quote the table names?

Also, do you happened to know where can I find the list of SQL differences between PostreSQL 9.4 and MySQL 5.6?

Comment: am using PostgreSQL with VB.NET never used `Public` keyword I think you need not use it ?? have tried without it ??

Comment: You are right. Now it worked for me. Is there anyway to have a universal query statement that can work with postgreSQL, MySQL, MSSQL? MySQL uses ``, postgreSQL uses "", MSSQL is fine without.

Comment: @furor: the `"` for quoted identifiers is required by the SQL standard. Both SQL Server and MySQL can be configured to comply with the standard regarding quoted identifiers.

Comment: Thank you guys, I will look into it. Hopefully I get can something by Friday.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your questions:
**(a) Make the searched text case-insensitive:**

you can use the ILIKE operator instead of LIKE. The ILIKE operator performs a case-insensitive pattern match.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name ILIKE '%abc%';
```

**(b) Avoid needing to add [public.] in front of the table name and to double-quote the table name:**

if you want to avoid specifying the schema and double-quoting the table name, you can set the search_path parameter in your PostgreSQL database.

Set Search Path:
In your PostgreSQL database run the following SQL command:

```
ALTER DATABASE [db_name] SET search_path TO public;
```

you can search normally like ..

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name ILIKE '%abc%';
```